# What is the current status of Foundation-of-Mathematics programmes?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, foundations-of-mathematics, axiom

I have been reading 'A Very Short Introduction to Mathematics' by Timothy Gowers and at one point he mentions that most of the mathematical proofs can be finally resolved to a set of logical statements. My past readings and further research on the topic bring me to a conclusion that the search for a logical foundation for Mathematics was in some sense a failed project and systems like ZFC and Principia Mathematica was only partially successful in grounding mathematics to pure logic and that proofs like Gödel's Incompleteness brought the search for foundations in pure logic to a complete halt.

I found out that some experts like C.S Peirce and Wittgenstein had a kind of "anti-foundationalist" stance.

> Not everyone agrees that logic does turn into math, in fact some philosophers, like C.S. Peirce has argued that math rather precedes logic, where the latter deals with the critique of (deductive) reasoning, while math is already in the world before any theory of reasoning is formulated. Logic can help in the meta-study of math, but at least the mature Peirce would say that math as a thing is prior to, and formally independent of, logic.
> https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/9p2tga/how_does_logic_turn_into_math/e7yr8fh/

Not quite sure if Wittgenstein remarked this in the context of being against foundations but nevertheless I found this to be in sync with my argument:

> As Wittgenstein remarks in the Investigations, just because you can express A in terms of B, it does not mean that B actually underlies A.
> https://mathoverflow.net/a/24871

And I found this analogy that goes with the Wittgenstein's quote above:

> As an analogy, ZFC is a foundation for mathematics in the same sense that the binary is a foundation for programming.
> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164379/are-axioms-truly-the-foundation-of-mathematics

Is it true to say that these so called foundational systems are actually just another representation rather than a solid foundation? (Like how binary is a representation for programming, maybe this is a stretch but something along the lines).

I came to know that there are also *multiple* approaches for building foundations like ETCS, ZFS etc. (Maybe Topos Theory, HoTT, Category Theory), which further suggests that they are more like alternative ways to sharpen how we see Mathematics and solve active problems than to be strong foundations:

> In mathematics, there are no decrees. Nobody has the right or power to decree any particular formal system as "the" foundations. You do things your own way, period. Foundational pluralism is, in some sense, inevitable.
> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292299/861378

I am increasingly coming to a conclusion that these foundations are just another way of seeing ordinary Mathematics rather than being a complete foundation:

> Mathematicians do not necessarily "work in" any foundations; ordinary mathematics actually has greater degree of self-evidence than its foundations.
> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945601/861378

Am I wrong in seeing the "foundations" this way? What is actually the current status of finding foundations for Mathematics? Can we really say that there are foundational projects anymore or are they just another way of seeing further horizons?

Comment: You have the right idea, see [Azzouni, Is there still a Sense in which Mathematics can have Foundations?](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Is-there-still-a-Sense-in-which-Mathematics-can-Azzouni/1b79cc627f78da702b16b8cd9161ccaba5703094):"*Since not even the consistency of a set of nonlogical axioms of any mathematical significance can be guaranteed, there seems little reason to hope for epistemic foundations... But second, ‘constitutional foundations’, aren’t forthcoming either... Which mathematical objects may be compounded out of which turns in large measure on sheer taste...*"